# PIC 16F684 Microcontroller Interupt Handling

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, microchip, interrupt

I just finished up my Microprocessors class in college just a few weeks ago, there we programmed in assembly only. We learned a fair amount (IMHO) about interrupts.

Here is my question: I am programming in C using the HiTech Compiler for the 16F684, in the datasheet section discussing the interrupts ([PIC 16F684 Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/cn/DeviceDoc/cn011811.pdf) Section 12.4) it says that the program will go to the interrupt vector 0x0004.  Using the assembly in my microprocessors class we would simply setup a .org statement pointing to that address and write the needed assembly below so when the interrupt occurs it would jump there and run. I can figure that out in assembly, but when I program in C I don't believe I have control over where program pieces are placed in memory, which presents a problem. I can't figure out how to place commands at the interrupt in C.

Please let me know if I need to clarify!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This FAQ by Microchip](http://www.microchipc.com/HiTechCFAQ/index.php#_Toc475127537) has some information about using interrupts under HiTech C.

Comment: It looks like the link you gave gives a good example as well. Thank you

Comment: I used the link you provided and got a test running, (just turning on an LED when the interrupt was hit). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

HiTech C extends the C language with the `interrupt` function type:

```
void interrupt my_interrupt_handler (void) {
    handle_interrupts_here();
}
```

You really should get the manual for the compiler. I believe the manual for the Pic-lite is free for download, at least it was when I downloaded my copy some time in 2001.

Comment: I'll have to give that a try. That statement is plug and play in the respect that if I have a function called handle_interrupts_here I can deal with them, or does "interrupt" get replaced with a type of interrupt per se?

Comment: PIC16 has only 1 'type' of interrupt. It's up to you to check the registers (HiTech defines them as global variables, check out the header files) to find out what happened.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to dig into the HiTech documentation, but often compilers have special keywords to define interrupt functions. The compiler, or the runtime system, has to deal with a function called by an interrupt specially: In addition to setting up the vector, the compiler (or runtime system) has to preserve all the registers. It might not have to do that for a normal, non-interrupt, function.

The manual will be your friend.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about the manual, for some reason I wasn't thinking something as simple as that would be in the manual...LOL

Answer (score 0):

The [CCS compiler for PICs](http://ccsinfo.com) uses #INT_* compiler directives or 'attributes' on interrupt handling functions for the various interrupt sources.